# xmlstarlet how to select tag immediately before selected tag

Tags: xml, xmllint, xmlstarlet

I scan scribus SLA files and wish to find the text having some specific paragraph styles.
SLA file format is a quite flat XML format and there are several paragraphs in a row, each being separated with either `<trail/>` or `<para/>` tags having a paragraphe style attribute. I can reach the `<StoryText>` object containing one of these, but i need to reach the tag `<ITEXT>` coming immediately before it because its CH attributes contains the text i'm looking for.

Here is how i reach the containing StoryText :

`xmlstarlet sel -t -c  "SCRIBUSUTF8NEW/DOCUMENT/PAGEOBJECT/StoryText [para/@PARENT='SearchedStyle']" myfile.sla`

It yields for example :

```
<StoryText>
    <DefaultStyle/>
    <ITEXT CH="Et main&#xAD;te&#xAD;nant"/>
    <breakline/>
    <ITEXT CH="qu&#x2019;est ce qu&#x2019;on fait&#x202F;?"/>
    <para PARENT="SomeOtherParagraphStyle"/>
    <para/>
    <ITEXT CH="The Calendar"/>
    <trail PARENT="SearchedStyle"/>
</StoryText>
```

I can also reach the `<trail PARENT="SearchedStyle"/>` but how can i reach the `<ITEXT CH="The Calendar"/>` node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it's the best solution, but here is how i managed to do it :

`xmlstarlet sel -t -c  "SCRIBUSUTF8NEW/DOCUMENT/PAGEOBJECT/StoryText/trail[@PARENT='SearchedStyle']/preceding-sibling::ITEXT[1]" myfile.sla`

And to get its `CH` attribute value :

`xmlstarlet sel -t -v  "SCRIBUSUTF8NEW/DOCUMENT/PAGEOBJECT/StoryText/trail[@PARENT='SearchedStyle']/preceding-sibling::ITEXT[1]/@CH" myfile.sla`

Woaw

Comment: In your XPath query, shouldn't `para` be `trail`, as there is no `para` node with the attribute `PARENT` with the value `SearchedStyle`?

Comment: Actually it can be both, hence the mistake. I edited to fix the mismatch.